# Nodejs Async waterfall in foreach loop is not working

Tags: node.js

I successfully implemented a waterfall into my node app,
this waterfall made 5 external calls to API and passing result to the next function.

Now i need to have that waterfall executed inside a loop :

```
function waterfallFbAdsMulti (productCollection)
{               
    async.forEach(productCollection, function(item, key, callback){

    console.log('forEachOfSeries');
    console.log(util.inspect(item));
    console.log(util.inspect(key));
    // THE ABOVE LOGS SHOWS THAT the forEach is fine

    async.waterfall([

     //WATERFALL DOING HER JOB      

     ], function(error, c) {
            return;
        });
     });
 }
```

Problem is that waterfall is not sync with the `forEach` events.
before that tried a raw js for loop with waterfall nested into a closure.. doesn't work as well.

Maybe I've missed some concept that maybe pretty obvious :/

Thank you very much for your attention.

CODE INSIDE THE WATERFALL :

```
async.waterfall([
        //GET AD ACCOUNT FOR USER

        function(callback) {  
                var sqlAd_act = vsprintf('select * from fbTokens  JOIN fbAdsParams ON fbTokens.userId=fbAdsParams.userId where fbTokens.userId=%s', [roomIDCook.userId]);

                connection.query(sqlAd_act).then(function(rows) {
                       /* SET FB TOKEN   */
                       fb.setAccessToken(rows[0].token);

                       //console.log(util.inspect(rows));

                       callback(null, rows , campaignTitle );
                       });                                  
                 },
                 //SET CAMPAIGN
                 function(rows, pTitlePassed, callback) {

                        console.log('pTitlePassed -> '+pTitlePassed)

                        fb.api('/act_' + rows[0].ad_act + '/campaigns', 'post', {
                                    'status': 'PAUSED',
                                    'name': campaignTitle ,
                                    'objective': 'LINK_CLICKS'
                        }, function(data) {
                                    //console.log('data: ' + util.inspect(data))
                                    console.log('CAMPAIGN -> '+campaignTitle);
                                    callback(null, data.id, rows);
                                });
                        },
                //SET ADSET
                function(campaignId, rows, callback) {

                        //console.log('ad account ' + rows[0].ad_act);
                        //console.log('campaignId ' + campaignId);

                        var startTimeAd = new moment().add(3, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DTHH:mm:ss+0000');
                        var endTimeAd = new moment().add(rows[0].duration, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DTHH:mm:ss+0000');

                        console.log('START AD AT : '+startTimeAd);
                        console.log('STOP AD AT : '+endTimeAd);

                        fb.api('/act_' + rows[0].ad_act + '/adsets', 'post', {
                                        'daily_budget': rows[0].budget*100,
                                        'start_time': startTimeAd,
                                        'end_time': endTimeAd,
                                        'name': campaignTitle+' ADSET',
                                        // 'optimization_goal': 'POST_ENGAGEMENT',
                                        'optimization_goal': 'LINK_CLICKS',
                                        // 'objective': 'POST_ENGAGEMENT',
                                        'objective': 'LINK_CLICKS',
                                        'campaign_id': campaignId,
                                        'status': 'PAUSED',
                                        // 'billing_event': 'POST_ENGAGEMENT',
                                        'billing_event': 'LINK_CLICKS',
                                        'is_autobid' : 'true' ,
                                        // 'bid_amount': 2,
                                        'targeting': {
                                            "geo_locations": {
                                                "countries": ["US"]
                                            },

                                            "publisher_platforms": ["facebook"]                                         
                                        }
                                    },

                              function(res) {

                                        if (!res || res.error) {
                                            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : util.inspect(res.error));
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        //console.log(util.inspect(res));
                                        msg.botreply = " Successfully created your adset !";
                                        msg.replyType = "info";
                                        io.sockets.in(msg.room).emit('receiveReply', msg);
                                        callback(null, res.id, rows)
                                    });
                            },
                      // CREATE THE AD FOR THE ADSET
                      function(adsetId, rows, callback) {

                                var imgUri = productCollection[i][i - 1].imageSrc;
                                var DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'shopifyImages/';
                                var imgName = productCollection[i][i - 1].productId;

                                console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);

                                request.head(imgUri, function(err, res, body) {

                                    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
                                    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

                                    var outputStream = request(imgUri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + imgName));

                                    outputStream.on('finish', function() {

                                        callback(null, DOWNLOAD_DIR+imgName, adsetId, rows);
                                    });
                                });
                            },

                            function(imgName, adsetId, rows, callback) {

                                fs.readFile(imgName , 'base64', function(err, data) {

                                    callback(null, data, adsetId, rows);

                                });
                            },

                            function(imgData, adsetId, rows, callback) {

                                fb.api('/act_' + rows[0].ad_act + '/adimages', 'post', {
                                        'bytes': imgData
                                    },

                                    function(res) {

                                        if (!res || res.error) {
                                            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        var imgHash = res.images.bytes.hash;
                                        //console.log(util.inspect(res.images.bytes.hash));
                                        msg.botreply = " Your image was successfully set for the Ad !"
                                        msg.replyType = "info2";
                                        io.sockets.in(msg.room).emit('receiveReply', msg);
                                        callback(null, adsetId, rows, imgHash);

                                    });
                            },

                            function(adsetId, rows, imgHash, callback) {

                                fb.api('/act_' + rows[0].ad_act + '/adcreatives', 'post', {
                                        'name': 'GENIE CREATIVE '+campaignTitle,
                                        "object_url": "http://www.direxit.com",
                                        "title": "My caption",
                                        "image_hash": imgHash,
                                        "link": "http://www.direxit.com",
                                        "body": "hjh"
                                    },

                                    function(res) {

                                        if (!res || res.error) {
                                            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        var adCreativeId = res.id;

                                        msg.botreply = " Your Ad creative was set as follow :<br>Name :"+ campaignTitle+"<br />Title :<br />Link :";
                                        msg.replyType = "info2";
                                        io.sockets.in(msg.room).emit('receiveReply', msg);
                                        callback(null, rows, adCreativeId, adsetId)
                                            //console.log('RESSSSSSSS '+util.inspect(res));
                                            //callback()    

                                    });
                            },

                            function(rows, adCreativeId, adsetId, callback) {


                                fb.api('/act_' + rows[0].ad_act + '/ads', 'post', {
                                        'name': 'AD 1000',
                                        "adset_id": adsetId,
                                        "creative": {
                                            "creative_id": adCreativeId
                                        },
                                        "status": "PAUSED",
                                    },

                                    function(res) {

                                        if (!res || res.error) {
                                            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        msg.botreply = " the Ad is ready !";
                                        msg.replyType = "info2";
                                        io.sockets.in(msg.room).emit('receiveReply', msg);
                                        console.log(util.inspect(res));

                                    });
                            }
                        ], function(error, c) {
                            return;
                        });
```

ALSO TRIED IN CLOSURE

[Tried with a closure function, same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH8Tv.png)

Comment: Could you provide the code within the `async.waterfall`?

Comment: @nikjohn the code is here, but i'm not sure its usefull, as i assume its more a sync / async problem inside the loop

Comment: From the documentation [here](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each), it looks like async.forEach _is_ sync.

Comment: yes i see , so i should quit looping with that forEach and use someting else to loop ? any idea ? :)

Comment: So technically this should work. What's the error you're facing?

Comment: You have an async waterfall within an async forEach loop. So I don't see a sync/async issue here. If you could provide info about what output you're getting, we might be able to help

Comment: @nikjohn, the problem is that the waterfall is only "running" with the value of the last iteration : last item of productCollection is always passed to the waterfall, will try again now to put the waterfall into a closure, maybe it will do it... :/

Comment: @nikjohn basically it gives on the console : 

item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4

waterfall item 4
waterfall item 4
waterfall item 4
waterfall item 4

Comment: Why not use `Promise.all`?

Comment: @nirvair because already broke my head with bluebird promises :)

Comment: Did you try this - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html
Works like a charm for me

Comment: could you tell me what  ' [roomIDCook.userId] ' is ?  Is roomIDCook the item  currently worked on buy forEachOf ? If its not, it means for all loops you are referring to the same item probably referenced from outside the forEachOf loop. That might explain why all the loop use the same item in their loop. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: just for clarification, it looks like you are using async.forEachOf .....and not async.each. Is that correct?